# DIV order and Z-Index

Tags: css, background, z-index

I just found the perfect way to show my background image for my photography website the way I want to. (through searching stackoverflow posts)

I took out what I had before in my code and replaced it with what I found with some minor edits. However, now neither the menu or anything else functions properly.

Ex. The links at the top of my page cant be clicked.

I think the background is covering the whole page and thats why. I tried removing the 'background' DIV from my code and it all worked again, but the background image is no longer position and used the way I want it too.

I think it's Z-Index related. Can someone help me fix this? and tell me why it is happening so I can avoid doing further in the code.

Here is the JsFiddle (for easy view/edit)
http://jsfiddle.net/3kke4/

```
body, html{
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin  : 0px;
    padding : 0px;}

#background{
    position    : absolute;
    top         : 0px;
    left        : 0px;
    overflow    : hidden;
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 100%;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-size   : 30px;}

.cover{
    position : absolute;
    width    : 100%;
    top      : 0px;
    z-index  : -1;} 

#container{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:40px;
}
.thumb{
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.5);}

#menu{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}

#menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:33px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;}

#menu li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}

#menu li a{
    float:left;
    color:#A79787;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:24px;
    padding:9px 15px 0;
    font-weight:normal;}

#menu li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.5);
    text-decoration:none;}

#toggle a{
    float:right;
    color:#A79787;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:24px;
    padding:9px 15px 0;
    font-weight:normal;}

#toggle a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.5);
    text-decoration:none;}

<body>
<div id='background'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/9dOAPlS.jpg' class='cover'/>
</div>
<div id='navigation'>
    <div>
    <ul id='menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Albums</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='toggle'>
        <a href='#'>Hide All</a>
    </div>       
</div>
<div id='container'>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: hi can you explain what is the purpose of `<div id='background'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/9dOAPlS.jpg' class='cover'/>
</div>` that background image intended for hole page or what?

Comment: Yeah, it is suppose to cover the entire page while remaining it's aspect ratio. Why?

Comment: is there another purpose for that because it is easy if you use that image background to your body example: `body {background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/9dOAPlS.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top center; /* you can manage where you want to position the image */ }`

Comment: If I do that the rest of the image would get cut off? It's a very large image. And not only that it's going to be a changing image. The use will click an arrow (left,right) to change the background to display a new photo.

It's a photo viewer website, a gallery... so the most important part for me is that the person sees the whole image at the best quality possible without creating a huge load time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the following styles (I've moved your `z-index` from `.cover` to `#background`):

```
#background{
    position    : absolute;
    top         : 0px;
    left        : 0px;
    overflow    : hidden;
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 100%;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-size   : 30px;
    z-index : -1;}

.cover{
    position : absolute;
    width    : 100%;
    top      : 0px;}
```

When something is positioned `absolute`ly, it then sits above the other elements. So in your case, you tried to offset that by putting the `z-index` on `.cover`. This won't work because `.cover` is a child of `#background`, and therefore it's `z-index` is relative to `#background` (which already sits above everything else).